# Skip zero entries while running the fishers test

Tags: r

My data frame looks like this

```
SYMBOL INTENSITY1 CALL1     PVALUE1 INTENSITY2 CALL2    PVALUE2  INTENSITY3 CALL3     PVALUE3
  CCL5         NA  <NA>    0.000         NA  <NA>         NA 1125.518318     P    0.000943658
CYP2A6  141.73193     A 0.060419342   102.5146     A 0.08940508  227.369549  A    0.218983229
CYP2E1   57.67287     P 0.024710915   134.4076     P 0.000000    6.090816    A    0.040000000
  DDR1 3242.90209     P 0.000218932         NA  <NA>         NA 7015.297075  P    0.000218932
 EPHB3   78.58733     A 0.234556513   453.3487     P 0.00222774  125.238085  A    0.418069378
```

I use the following code to calculate the p-values by Fisher's method

```
Fisher.test <- function(p) {
  Xsq <- -2*sum(log(p))
  p.val <- pchisq(Xsq, df = 2*length(p), lower.tail = FALSE)
  return(c( p.value = p.val)) #
}
```

**Credit to Tim Biegeleisen**

```
p.cols <- grep("PVALUE", names(data))
data$Fishers <- apply(data[, names(data)[p.cols]], 1, function(x) Fisher.test(x))
```

Now the issue here is the entries of zeros in the rows. In the first row i have the `PVALUE` entries as `0.000, 0.00094365` and if I calculate `Fisher.test` on `c(0.000, 0.00094365) , it give the result as zero, but the correct result is 0.00094365. So i need to skip the zero entries of the rows from passing through the`Fisher.test`.

**Desired output**

```
SYMBOL INTENSITY1 CALL1     PVALUE1 INTENSITY2 CALL2    PVALUE2  INTENSITY3 CALL3     PVALUE3        Fisher's
      CCL5       NA   <NA>    0.000        NA     <NA>         NA   1125.518318   P       0.000943658  0.000943658
      CYP2A6  141.73193 A     0.060419342 102.5146  A      0.08940508  227.369549 A       0.218983229  0.03602191
      CYP2E1  57.67287  P  0.024710915    134.4076  P      0.000000    6.090816 A       0.040000000    0.007828
      DDR1    3242.90209 P 0.000218932         NA  <NA>         NA 7015.297075    P       0.000218932  0.0000008557
      EPHB3   78.58733   A 0.234556513    453.3487   P    0.00222774  125.238085  A       0.418069378  0.00982
```

Comment: Try `apply(data[, names(data)][p.cols]], 1, function(x) Fisher.test(x[x!=0]))`

Comment: @akrun Mr Perfect ....

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We can remove the 0 elements in each row before applying the `Fisher.test`

```
apply(data[, names(data)][p.cols]], 1, function(x) Fisher.test(x[x!=0]))
```